# How to replicate address bar behaviour of Chrome app

Tags: ios, objective-c

Does anybody know if there is some project or something that replicates the address bar behaviour of the chrome app in iOS? That is, when scrolling down, it hides, and if I'm in the middle of the table, and I scroll up, the address bar appears.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way most navigation hiding works is by listening to scroll events from the scroll/table/web view and adjusting the center of the navigation bar.

You would make your view controller a delegate of the view in question and apply some level of logic:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    CGPoint navigationBarCenter = self.navigationController.navigationBar.center;

    // A bunch of calculations
    navigationBarCenter.y = newlyCalculatedPosition;

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.center = navigationBarCenter;
}
```

For this specific behavior, they are calculating from where scrolling started and saying "If I'm scrolling down, the navigation bar center should be its original center minus the distance scrolled.  If I'm scrolling up, the navigation bar center should be increasing from just off screen to its normal position.

You then have to make decisions about what to do when scrolling ends and your nav bar is partly on screen.  Do you show it all or just part?

Pre-iOS7, you also have to worry about the frame of the scroll view.  The iOS7 default behavior is to have view controllers expand to the full size of the device, while the iOS6 default behavior is to fill the space between the nav bar and toolbar.  You can address this by using a translucent navigation bar, but will need to adjust your content and scroll indicator insets to limit the content to the inner area when not scrolled.

Comment: Thing is that I want the table header or the section table header to be hidden/shown, not the navigation bar. I'm already doing something like what you've posted, checking the contentOffset and that sort of things, but I just wanted to know if there is some github project or some tableview reusable code that behaves likes this.

Thanks

Comment: I would be very careful about trying to manipulate table headers and section headers. A) The positions of these are carefully calculated internally and B) cell calculation is done after the scroll delegate methods are called so you would have to do subclassing.